# Summation notation conversion to multiplication in attached equation.. How? Please explain.

Tags: information-theory

[image]

[image]

Can any one please tell me how summation sign has been changed to multiplication in 2nd and 3rd equation and inequality also changed to equal sign.

Comment: $\log_2a+\log_2b=\log_2ab$ for $a,b>0$

Answer (score 1):

This is just using the fact that $\log(a\cdot b) = \log a + \log b$ (true for any particular base of the logarithm). Stated more generally, it becomes $\log \prod_{\alpha}x_{\alpha} = \sum_{\alpha}\log x_{\alpha}$.

That particular law of logarithms is a restatement of the fact that $x^u\cdot x^v = x^{u+v}$.

Comment: but why equality changed?

Comment: @MAJadoon: The expression on the third line is identically equal to the expression on the second line. But the inequality from above is still correct for comparison to the *first* line. For example, if $X\leq Y=Z$, then you still have $X\leq Z$, right?